# Custom UIViews For Collage App

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, calayer

I am working on a collage application, and I have successfully build the simple collages but now I am stuck on how to build complex style collages like in the following image
[image: Stylish Collage]

How I will be able to create the custom view like in the image, I have tried using Beizerpath and by applying masking to the view with the path of the beizerpath, but I am not able to add shadow to the layer when I apply the mask to the view. Any help would be appreciated. How can I exactly create the type of view in the image with the shadow behind them?

Answer (score 1):

Asking for somebody to tell you exactly how to implement your app's features is not appropriate for this site.

Look a using CAShapeLayers and setting their various shadow properties, like shadowOpacity, shadowRadius, shadowOffset, shadowColor, and shadowPath.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
   import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var image1: UIImageView!  // your image outlet
    override func viewDidLoad() {


super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {



          let trianglePath = UIBezierPath()
        trianglePath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: image1.frame.size.height - 60))
        trianglePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:0, y: image1.frame.size.height))
        trianglePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: image1.frame.size.width, y: image1.frame.size.height))
        trianglePath.close()
        let path = UIBezierPath(rect: view.bounds)

        path.append(trianglePath)


        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.frame = image1.bounds

        maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd

        maskLayer.path = path.cgPath

        image1.layer.mask = maskLayer



    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

And more shapes [link appcoda](https://www.appcoda.com/bezier-paths-introduction/)